# Windows desktop remains extended to secondary display even though the display has been switched off

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-11, nvidia-graphics-card

I use my **AOC 27B2DA** as a secondary display (HDMI port from my NVIDIA GTX 1660 Super).  When I turn it off by pressing its power button, it is still detected in Windows 11 display settings.

I have used other monitors as secondary displays, but this is the first time I have encountered this issue.

I know I can press Windows P and select "Display only on monitor 1" but this is not the solution I want.

Similar to my prior secondary displays, I want to control whether the Windows desktop is extended to my secondary display or not using the on/off state of the power button on the display.

I tried uninstalling the display driver to no effect. I also searched forum posts but found nothing pertinent.

Comment: Does it still register if you unplug it from the wall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Tesujin alluded to in [his comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1766468/monitor-stays-detected-in-windows-after-i-turn-it-off-manually#comment2749078_1766468), when switched off, your display is not *completely* off.

#### AOC 27B2DA Power Consumption

| State | Consumption (watts) |
| --- | --- |
| On | 22 USA<sup>*****</sup> (22 EU) |
| Standby | 0.3 USA<sup>*****</sup> (0.5 EU) |
| Off | 0.3 USA<sup>*****</sup> (0.5 EU) |

***** *USA power specifications prepended* `≈` *to the* values

##### Display Mode Shortcut

---

As you stated, there are some simple  Windows shortcuts that are intended to manage display presentation modes.  I understand you don't want to use them, but I am including them for others who may find your post and are not as computer savvy as you are.
**Windows Desktop on `PC Screen Only`:**

1. **<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>**
2. Select<sup>*****</sup> `PC Screen Only`
3. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *or* <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

**Windows Desktop `Extend` to AOC:**

1. **<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>**
2. Select<sup>*****</sup> `Extend`
3. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> *or* <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

***** *You do not need to use your mouse***️***or **<kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd>** keys to cycle through the options.  You can press* **<kbd>P</kbd>** *one or more additional times to achieve the same effect.*

---

##### Modern Display Switching

The source of your problem is the change in how modern electronics are designed.  Increased complexity (e.g. built-in speakers, USB hubs, etc.) as well as changing expectations (e.g. quick power on from off) all contribute to the fact that few displays ever shut completely off.

Modern displays like your **AOC 27B2DA** are designed to enter into and resume from `sleep/stand by/suspend` modes (the new *off*) based on triggers from the OS or the absence of a video signal.

There is no difference in power consumption from your AOC being switched *"off"* versus going into `sleep/stand by/suspend` mode (both ≈0.3 watts).

The manufacturer expects you to leverage Windows' native display switching to enable and disable `Extend` mode to your AOC display, not use its power button for this particular purpose.

The table below compares the main approaches to **disable** `Extend` mode on your AOC display and **restore** `PC Screen Only` mode.

| Approach | Display | OS | Still to do |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Power Button (AOC) | blank (≈0.3 watts) | Multi-display | PC Screen Only (Win) |
| PC Screen Only (Win) | blank (≈0.3 watts) | PC Screen Only (Win) | - |
| Pull Plug (AOC) | blank (**0 watts**) | PC Screen Only (Win) | - |

**<kbd>⊞ Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>** <kbd>ENTER</kbd> seems relatively painless for most users but if you want to avoid the Windows shortcuts, you might look at one of changing to a display with a true *off* state, cutting and restoring the power to the AOC display to simulate the same (power bar switch?), or cutting and restoring the HDMI signal (HDMI switch?).

#### Additional Resources

---

Microsoft Windows Support:  [Keyboard shortcuts in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/keyboard-shortcuts-in-windows-dcc61a57-8ff0-cffe-9796-cb9706c75eec)

AOC 27B2DA Specifcations:    [USA](https://www.displayspecifications.com/en/model/4f32218a)   |   [EU](https://eu.aoc.com/en/products/monitors/27b2da/specification)